# SQL Server - Select * vs Select Column in a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

In an ad-hoc query using Select ColumnName is better, but does it matter in a Stored Procedure after it's saved in the plan guide?

Comment: **Y E S ! !** it matters! I would recommend to **always** explicitly specify the columns you want. Otherwise: what happens if someone (a DBA or other dev) suddenly adds three BLOB columns to your table? Your stored procedure using `SELECT *` will grab **all those columns** - even if you don't need them at all. See [Bad habits to kick: using SELECT * / omit the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list) for a great discussion

Comment: If someone is stupid enough to add 3 BLOB columns to any table that worked fine without them, let them get in trouble... or tll 'em to use horizontal partitioning (if you're a good Samaritan).

Comment: @Serge - What? You create a new table every time you get a requirement to add a new BLOB column just to cater for people that might have used `*`?

Comment: @Martin almost, because BLOB almost always means "optional extra data" you access now and then added to a "crucial compact row" you access very often.

Comment: @Serge Expecting that others will always do the "right" thing is in itself wrong.  You should code defensively.  Just like driving...  you avoid accidents by assuming that others *will* do the wrong thing.  I would use "select *" is from my own temp table, table variable, or CTE.  Or else if I explicitly need ALL columns from a table, even if the table changes, e.g. when archiving table rows as XML.

Answer (score 5):

Always explicitly state the columns, even in a stored procedure. `SELECT *` is considered bad practice.

For instance you don't know the column order that will be returned, some applications may be relying on a specific column order.

I.e. the application code may look something like:

```
Id = Column[0]; // bad design
```

If you've used `SELECT *` ID may no longer be the first column and cause the application to crash.  Also, if the database is modified and an additional 5 fields have been added you are returning additional fields that may not be relevant.

Comment: Prove, it's always a bad practice please.

Comment: Darren... me too. I am at a new place and see it select * used a lot. So I was like scratching my head and don't want to say anything before I make sure I didn't miss anything.

Comment: @user2505334 / Serge. Updated my answer to include why.

Comment: @Darren, relying on column order is the bad practice to avoid before any other ones. But I'll give you that, preventing trouble to external bad practices users makes perfect sense. +1

Comment: Another example of column index issue: for long-running projects the table columns may be added using scripts. Sometimes column order in debug environment and on production database may mismatch. In such case SELECT * will return columns in different order. This may ruin statements like `UNION SELECT`, `ORDER BY 1,3,5`, etc.

Comment: @Artemix - Though `ORDER BY 1,3,5` is not something that should ever be in production code either IMO.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, but this option exists in SQL anyway, so it's better to be warned.

Comment: I don't consider `SELECT *` to be 'bad practice', there are situations where it makes good sense to use it, and situations where you shouldn't.

Comment: @Goat_CO - In a normal query, `SELECT *` can be useful if you need all of the columns in a table and need write a quick query.  However specifying `SELECT *` in a stored procedure is bad practice for the reasons I have pointed out in my answer.

Comment: You make an absolute claim, which I do not agree with, the vast majority of the time I agree that it's best practice to list fields, but not always.

Answer (score 1):

These topics always elicit blanket statements like ALWAYS do this or NEVER do that, but the reality is, like with most things it depends on the situation.  I'll concede that it's typically good practice to list out columns, but whether or not it's bad practice to use `SELECT *` depends on the situation.

Consider a variety of tables that all have a common field or two, for example we have a number of tables that have different layouts, but they all have 'access_dt' and 'host_ip'. These tables aren't typically used together, but there are instances when suspicious activity prompts a full report of all activity.  These aren't common, and they are manually reviewed, as such, they are well served by a stored procedure that generates a report by looping through every log table and using `SELECT *` leveraging the common fields between all tables.

It would be a waste of time to list out fields in this situation.

Again, I agree that it's typically good practice to list out fields, but it's not ***always*** bad practice to use `SELECT *`.

Edit: Tried to clarify example a bit.

Comment: Your example with the "analysis across tables" is not clear at all. How would `SELECT *` be used?

Comment: For outputting all fields from a number of tables based on only a few fields common to all of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

It's a best practice in general but if you actually do need all the column, you'd better use the quickly read "SELECT *".

The important thing is to avoid retreiving data you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

It is considered bad practice in situations like stored procedures when you are querying large datasets with table scans.  You want to avoid using table scans because it causes a hit to the performance of the query.  It's also a matter of readability.

Answer (score 0):

SOme other food for thought. If your query has any joins at all you are returning data you don't need because the data in the join columns is the same. Further if the table is later changed to add some things you don't need (such as columns for audit purposes) you may be returning data to the user that they should not be seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody has mentioned the case when you need ALL columns from a table, even if the columns change, e.g. when archiving table rows as XML.  I agree one should not use "SELECT *" as a replacement for "I need all the columns that currently exist in the table," just out of laziness or for readability.  There needs to be a valid reason.  It could be essential when one needs "all the columns that *could* exist in the table."

Also, how about when creating "wrapper" views for tables?